# Adding Chrome Webdriver with python script while converting it to exe

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have automated a task using selenium in python and now I am compiling exe from that script.
From what I know I wrote this piece of code in my script.

```py
PATH = "/home/blackhawk/tools/webdriver/chrome/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
```

Here the script is using chromdriver from my machine. Currently, my application is explicitly asking for the path of chromedriver.
Is there any way I can add this file inside my application.
What changes I should do to my PATH varible as well to make it work.

[Here is the repository with test.py](https://github.com/mayankbist45/MyClassBot)

Comment: Add what file? ChromeDriver?

Comment: Yes I want to bundle all chrome driver versions (85, 86, 87) though. But for now I want to learn how to bundle one chromedriver with my script. @GregBurghardt